# Corresponding control in WPF to WinForms DropdownButton?

Tags: wpf, winforms, button

Is there a corresponding control in WPF to the WinForms DropDownButton? If not, any ideas on the best workaround for the same type of functionality? I want to have a button at the bottom of the right of the form that provides two distinct but related types of functionality, such as a "Make Pie" button:

```
MAKE PIE
     From Scratch
     From a Box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) has this control.

[Here is a guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-dropdownbutton-control/) on using it.